# Can't get toBeCalled() working in Jade test script

Tags: javascript, tdd, jestjs

I can't get `toBeCalled()` working in my Jade test script.

I get the following error msg when run the Jade test:

`Error: toBeCalled() should be used on a mock function or a jasmine spy`

I have a call to `jest.unmock('../fooey')` so not sure why I'm getting the error ?

fooey.js

```
var foo = function(phrase) {
    return bar(phrase);
}

var bar = function(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + " Watz up?");
}

foo("Hi Bob!");

module.exports.foo = foo;

module.exports.bar = bar;
```

fooey-test.js:

```
jest.unmock('../fooey'); // unmock to use the actual implementation.

describe('fooey()', () => {

   const foo = require('../fooey').foo;
   const bar = require('../fooey').bar;

   it('bar() is called.', () => {

      foo("Hi Bob!");

      expect(bar).toBeCalled();
   });
});
```

Comment: I was following the Jest tutorial where they call `jest.unmock('../fetchCurrentUser.js');`. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial.html#content

Comment: After reading up on mocks in Jest, I don't think that's what I need. I want to call `foo()` and have Jest tell me if bar `()` was called from within `foo()`.

Comment: I got this working using spyOn(), although I had to wrap foo() and bar() in a wrapper func() to work as per spyOn() API requiring the spied function to be within the same object. i.e.       ```spyOn(fooey, 'bar');

      fooey.foo("Hi Bob!");

      expect(fooey.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Hi Bob!");```

Question 1) is there a better way to do this with Jest API, 2) can I do this without putting my code into a wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with both a mock of bar() and also using spyOn()...

fooey.js

```
var Fooey = function() {
    // var self = this;

    this.foo = function(phrase) {
        // var result = self.bar(phrase);
        var result = this.bar(phrase);

        return result;
        // return "Junky."
    };

    this.bar = function(greeting) {
        var result = greeting + " Watz up?"

        console.log(result);

        return result;
    };
};


module.exports = Fooey;
```

fooey-test.js

```
jest.unmock('../fooey'); // unmock to use the actual implementation.

describe('fooey()', () => {

   const Fooey = require('../fooey');
   const fooey = new Fooey();

  it('mock: bar() is called.', () => {

      var myFooey = {
         foo: fooey.foo,
         bar: jest.genMockFunction()         
      };

      myFooey.foo("Hello");

      expect(myFooey.bar).toBeCalledWith("Hello");
   });

   it('bar() is called with "Hi Bob!".', () => {

      spyOn(fooey, 'bar');

      fooey.foo("Hi Bob!");

      expect(fooey.bar).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Hi Bob!");
   });
});
```